# I overstayed my UK visa in the past and returned voluntary, will that harm my Dutch Student Visa?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen-visas, netherlands, student-visas

The passport I am applying with doesn't have any travel history.
I have paid the tuition fees in full, plus also one year expenses which is like 20,000 Euros in total.
ILETS Score 7
Received university acceptance.
My High School Diploma is qualified.
Would that be enough ?

Comment: What was the _actual_ result to you, after voluntarily leaving? Ban? Duration? When did the overstay occur, and when were you asked to leave, or when did you leave on your own without being asked?

Answer (score 4):

Bans and visa denials and removals all apply to the *person* and not to the *document*. Even if your current passport is new and different, your history can still be discovered and connected to you.

Whether the good stuff you mention will outweigh any bad stuff will be up to the Dutch visa authorities. The only way to know for sure is to apply.

Comment: hmm, different question here, and yes, I should see if it has been asked and answered, but honestly, lazy, I guess. Post-Brexit, are the database(s) still used/shared between the UK and EU? (I don't say Schengen here, as I don't know the ramifications of Brexit upon UK vis-a-vis Schengen)